# Динамическое изменение ширины UIImage

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

У меня есть такой UIImage c UITextField вместо имени "Константин". При введении имени длина обрамляющих текст сверху и снизу полосок должна ограничиваться длиной имени по левому краю. Текст в текстфилде соответственно прицеплен к правому краю, моя задача уменьшать фрейм картинки слева по закрытию клавиатуры после набора имени. Использую

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
            ruleImage.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1,1);
            [ruleImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120 + ruleTextfield.text.length * 15 , ruleImage.frame.size.height)];
}
```

но этот код сжимает картинку по горизонтали а не обрезает. Как именно обрезАть ее по левому краю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.png"];

CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0));
CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([myImage CGImage], cropRect);

UIImage *myCroppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage];

CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
```

Comment: Благодарю за решение, Александр!